# Wix Velo Form Posting

Tags: javascript, velo

I am trying to make the following form code work on a Wix website.

It is code for an opt-in subscription form. The user enters their details and is then redirected to a third-party site where a CAPTCHA verification is done and further redirects are executed.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Form Starts -->
<form action="https://app.birdsend.co/subscribe" method="post" bs-form>
  <input type="hidden" name="meta_id" value="{id_value}">
  <input type="hidden" name="meta_user_id" value="{user_id_value}">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter first name...">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter daily email..." required>
  <button type="submit">&gt; Subscribe</button>
  <div id="bs-message"></div>
</form>
<script>
  (function(w, d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://cdn.birdsend.co/assets/static/js/form.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(window, document, 'script', 'birdsend-form-js'));
</script>
<!-- Form Ends -->
```

I have created an opt-in subscription form on wix with the necessary fields. I am able to read the form's contents using Velo but get the following error upon submission to the server:

> Error: Failed to fetch

I have narrowed the error down to the specific part of the code where the submission is made to the server.

Here is my Velo code:

```
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';

// POST call using fetch
export async function postSubscribe(form_body) {

    const fetchOptions = {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: form_body

    };

    let post_url = "https://app.birdsend.co/subscribe";

    console.log("Start Post");
    const response = await fetch(post_url, fetchOptions); //ERROR OCCURS HERE - EXECUTION STOPS AT THIS LINE

    console.log("End Post"); //THIS LINE DOES NOT EXECUTE

    return response;
}

$w.onReady(function () {

    // Write your Javascript code here using the Velo framework API
    let form_body = ""

    $w("#getSubscribers1").onWixFormSubmit(async ({ fields }) => {

        console.log("Form Submitted");
        let data = {
            first_name: encodeURIComponent($w("#input2").value),
            email: encodeURIComponent($w("#input1").value),
            meta_id: encodeURIComponent("{id_value}"),
            meta_user_id: encodeURIComponent("{user_id_value}")
        }

        form_body = "first_name=" + data.first_name + "&email=" + data.email + "&meta_id=" + data.meta_id + "&meta_user_id" + data.meta_user_id;

         console.log(form_body)

        const post_response = await postSubscribe(form_body); 

        console.log(post_response); 

    });
});
```

Any suggestions from those who are familiar with Velo?